# Unable to add base64 png images to JSPDF Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, base64, png, jspdf

```
 function save_pdf() {
 var doc = new jsPDF();  
 var imgSampleData ='data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEA8ADwAAD/2w...';
 doc.addImage(btoa(imgSampleData), 'PNG', 15, 40, 175, 75);
 doc.save('MCR.pdf');
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

When I pass base64 strings from one of the webservices I am unable to add these base64s to images of JSPDF below is the error I get in IE

***Incomplete or corrupt PNG file***

[image]

I have attached entire base64 String of whole image. This Base64 works fine and able to see images if I use any online conversion tool.

[Attachement base64 png string](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRwV-8m4H86VHpFS1VFVFU4OWs/view?usp=sharing)

What could be the reason why JSPDF unable to parse this type of base64 strings and other seems to parse the String Successfully?

Comment: Try to copy paste the base64 string in the url bar of your browser. If you are not able to see the image, then string might be corrupt.

Comment: Thanks @elarmando string is working fine! so not corrupt

Comment: I see you are invoking btoa function, if the  string is already in base64, there is no need to invoke btoa

Comment: JSpdf shoots the same error even after removing btoa @elarmando could you please try too? I have attached entire base64 string in the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Base64 Data of Image is JPEG, So was the error.

```
var imgSampleData ='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEA8ADwAAD/2w...';
```

`data:image/png` has to be changed to `data:image/jpeg` and JSPDF fails to recognise that if the Data is jpeg and fails at the above line. I raise an issue with JSPDF Reagrding this.

Comment: That is not always the case, I've the same problem, a valid base64 image that throws the same error (Incomplete or corrupted...).
Modifying the base64 image type do not solves the problem.